# git filter-branch only change affected commits

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

A large binary file was added to my git repository 20 commits ago. Removing this with:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch FILE" \
    --prune-empty HEAD
```

changes the SHA1 for every commit (~1100) in my projects history. It does remove the file, but I was hoping to only have `git push -f` a small number of modified commits. Is there a way to tell `filter-branch` to only modify commits with `FILE` and descendant comments, in my case around 20 commits?

Comment: I believe the reason every SHA1 changes is because it updates the committer info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know what commit introduced the file, the simplest way is to specify `$SHA^..HEAD` (where `$SHA` is the commit that introduced it). This will prevent it from even looking at older commits.

If the commit that introduced this file *only* introduced it, and nothing more, and no other commits since then touched it, then you can get rid of it even simpler without a filter-branch, by using `git rebase --onto $SHA^ $SHA` (where `$SHA` is the commit that introduced this file). That will simply drop the commit `$SHA` from history.

Comment: The first suggestion works well. In this case the commit contains many other changes (part of the reason the binary ended up in there in the first place). Thanks for teaching me the --onto flag though!